# Im trying to position 9 images in a 3x3 format to line perfectly

Tags: html, css, image

IM trying to create a 3x3 grid on my website with 9 images with text under. the first 6 images looks as i want but when i add the last 3 images the first image jumps under the 3rd image on second line and the 2 last images go way down.

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbbj1e6q/

html:

```
<div class="member bordadd"> <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Bacau.jpg" alt="Responsive image" /> <div class="name"><span>Bacau du rouet</span></div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is already in 3*3 format. Drag result portion of fiddle in full width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that´s because the lenght of the text, if the content was the same you won´t have the problem, I recommend to include all the text in a layer width a height in order to have all the boxes width the same height.. and adjust the content to that layer or make some script to show the content on hover or someting

Comment: This worked! thank you, i just wrapped the text in a div and set a width and height for them all and they line perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a white-space: nowrap to the design-cast id it should be displayed properly. Though you need to readjust the texts under the images:

```
#design-cast {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap; //Add this
}
```

Check out the updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jbbj1e6q/1/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried it and after adjusting the text i got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: flex` for this:

```css
/*

*/
.white-background {
  background-color: #FCFBE3;
}
.site-content {
  background-color: #FCFBE3;
}
h1 {
  color: black !important;
}
.dashed-border {
  border-top: none;
}

div.item {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 290px;
  margin-left: 13%;
}
.ext1 {
  margin-left: 25% !important;

}

img {

}
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
}
.storbild {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#search-button {
  display:none;
}
#fixrow1 {
  margin-left: 125px;
}
#design-cast {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.member {
  width: 32%;
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;

}
.name {
  bottom:0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.member img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.descript {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.bordadd {
  border: 2px solid #e5e5e5 !important;
}
.fixsamesize {
  width: 333px;
  height: 210px;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}
.fixsamesize:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.viewmorehorse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="design-cast">
  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Boyzon.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Boyzon st Tropez</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Gelding
      2006
      Bleckert boy x Saluut
      <b>Owner:</b> Yvonne Talamo & Björn Häggström
      <b>Level:</b> 145
      A horse that has made so much for us and will always stay in the family.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Bacau.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Bacau du rouet</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2012
      Baltimore x Callahan vdl
      <b>Owner:</b> Vivi-Anne Ohlsson & Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b> 125
      Really scoopy horse that definitely going to go really big classes in the future.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Aldenalyx.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Aldenalyx</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2008
      Cartier x For feeling
      <b>Owner:</b>  René Fluck & Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b> 135
      A clear round machine which is both fast and careful. The perfect horse for someone who likes ribbons!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/CassandraS.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Cassandra S</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2006
      Cosmopolite S- Caretino
      <b>Owner:</b> Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b> 135
      Supernice horse with much left to give! She has all potential to be a top horse for a junior or yr.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/ChickFlick.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Chick Flick K</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2008
      Hip Hop x Zeppelin
      <b>Owner:</b> Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b> 150
      A horse with a fantastic mentality. She always wants to go clear and has the potential to go all the way to the top.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Horatio.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Color me grey ASMZ</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2011
      Cicero Z x Graf Granus
      <b>Owner:</b> Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b>
      Fantastic horse for the top sport. Really careful and scoopy.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/CassandraS.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Cassandra S</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2006
      Cosmopolite S- Caretino
      <b>Owner:</b> Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b> 135
      Supernice horse with much left to give! She has all potential to be a top horse for a junior or yr.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/ChickFlick.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Chick Flick K</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2008
      Hip Hop x Zeppelin
      <b>Owner:</b> Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b> 150
      A horse with a fantastic mentality. She always wants to go clear and has the potential to go all the way to the top.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="member bordadd">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail fixsamesize" src="http://www.aphhorses.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Horatio.jpg" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name"><span>Color me grey ASMZ</span></div>
    <p class="descript viewmorehorse">Klicka för att se mer</p>
    <p class="descript">Mare
      2011
      Cicero Z x Graf Granus
      <b>Owner:</b> Katarina Pettersson
      <b>Level:</b>
      Fantastic horse for the top sport. Really careful and scoopy.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This made all 9 images show up in a straight horizontal line.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you checked my code? If you only use `display: flex`, yes then everything is in one line. But my code has some more code.